# Grails <g:actionSubmit> redirects to GSP instead of action

Tags: grails, gsp

I have created a new action called "updateWithHistory" on a controller "X" similar to update. When I use this code from a scaffolded edit.gsp page:

`<span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="save" action="updateWithHistory" value="${message(code: 'default.button.updateWithHistory.label', default: 'Persist')}" /></span>`

I get a 404 error:

`The requested resource (/GPECAN/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/X/updateWithHistory.jsp) is not available.`

I don't know why Grails is looking for the view and not for the action. I don't need a view for that action because it redirects to existing actions (list, edit, etc.).

This does not happen with the default scaffolded actions like "update". Any ideas?

(Of course, if I create a view called "updateWithHistory.gsp", the view is shown, but the action is never executed...I'm desperate)

Comment: Can you give us the code for the `updateWithHistory` method in the `X` controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm just stupid. It was an uncatched error in my controller; the error situation was ocurring but there was not specific view to handle it, so the controller tried to redirect to an unexisting default view.

Sorry a lot for my stupidity and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your problem, depending what you want to achieve.
First thing that you have to know is quote from documentation:

> Also note that this tag relies on the
>   multipart resolver to be able to
>   inspect parameters included with
>   mulitpart requests. If you disable the
>   resolver by setting
>   grails.disableCommonsMultipart to true
>   in Config.groovy, actionSubmit will
>   not work.

So two solutions:

1. Set 'controller' attribute in [g:form tag](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+form)
2. Create URL mapping as [described here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)

P.S. If you want to see any 'renderable' result by browser you have to use controller's dynamic **render** method :)

Answer (score 1):

You have probably bug in your controller. After your action you need to [render](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) something or [redirect](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html). Take a good look on scaffolded controller code.

Try to add following on the end of your *updateWithHistory* action.

```
render(view: "edit", model: [yourDomainInstance: yourDomainInstance])
```